# Gradle warns about a configuration that doesn't exist in my build.gradle file

Tags: android, gradle

Gradle gives the warning:

> Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.

There is no "compile" configuration in my build.gradle file, so why is it giving me this warning?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ktoi.toi"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }
}
kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}
buildscript {
    ext.supportVersion = '25.0.0'
    ext.daggerVersion = '2.7'
    ext.retrofitVersion = '2.1.0'
    ext.rxVersion = '1.2.1'
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:2.1.1"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${supportVersion}"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:${supportVersion}"

    // Dagger 2
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:${daggerVersion}"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:${daggerVersion}"
    compileOnly "org.glassfish:javax.annotation:3.1.1"

    //Retrofit 2
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:${retrofitVersion}"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:${retrofitVersion}"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:${retrofitVersion}"

    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'

    implementation "io.reactivex:rxjava:${rxVersion}"
    implementation "io.reactivex:rxandroid:${rxVersion}"

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'

  }
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Comment: Do you have other modules in your project?

Comment: No. I also searched the entire project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`realm-gradle-plugin:2.1.1` is old and [old versions of the plugin add `compile` dependencies](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/8055b1772f89998a87f3bb9e26ccdd0591615589/gradle-plugin/src/main/groovy/io/realm/gradle/Realm.groovy#L60). Newer versions of the plugin correctly [add `api` dependencies in place of `compile` if your project has those](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/789740d8050ba020c8990fd7983fb709b748f7b3/gradle-plugin/src/main/groovy/io/realm/gradle/Realm.groovy#L99).

As of now, 5.8.0 is the newest version on [bintray](https://bintray.com/realm/maven/realm-gradle-plugin).

Comment: (You seem to have a number of other quite old dependencies there.)

Comment: But what does the version have to do with configuration "compile"?

Comment: The old version of the plugin is configuring your project in an old-fashioned way that emits warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Similar issue has been reported. Check this https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/74048134

There also is problem with older google services version. make sure you are using `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'` or higher in your app level gradle.

Comment: The dependencies are already compiled, they don't affect the current project

Comment: won't they be using compile if the version used is older enough?

Comment: It does not matter what setup they were built with. maven artefacts used as dependencies are just jar/aar  files and xml metadata, nothing to `compile` there.

Comment: I don't see OP using any version of google-services. But if he was, an old version could be an issue since it's a plugin that configures the project.

Comment: might be helpful for somebody else. keeping it here.

Answer (score 0):

```
Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
```

This is due to, one of your dependencies uses compile instead of Implementation

Comment: It's none of the dependencies in the `dependencies` block though; see my comment to Karan Mer's anwer.

Answer (score -2):

Use

```
implementation "org.glassfish:javax.annotation:3.1.1"
```

instead of

```
compileOnly "org.glassfish:javax.annotation:3.1.1"
```

Comment: `compileOnly` is the current alternative for old `provided` dependencies. https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies